# How to delete a document from a mongodb collection when some date is smaller than new Date()

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to delete (while importing new documents) some documents from my `MongoDB` collection, when some `date` in the document is smaller than `new Date()`.

Everytime I import a document, I check, if there is a document with the same `STATION_ID` that needs to be deleted.

Now I'm doing it like this using mongoose:

```
function doTheStuff(stationid, time, callback) {
  OwnMetarDoc.find({
    STATION_ID: stationid[0]
  }, function(err, entry) {
    var isTaf = false;
    if (entry[0] != undefined) {
      if (entry[0].TIME) {
        var entryObjectTimerec = entry[0].TIME;
        var isTaf = true;
      };
      var d = new Date;
      var month = d.getUTCMonth();
      var year = d.getUTCFullYear();
      var timeRecConverted = new Date(year, month, parseInt(entryObjectTimerec.substring(0, 2)),
          parseInt(entryObjectTimerec.substring(2, 4)), parseInt(entryObjectTimerec.substring(4, 6)));
      //The relevant part
      if (timeRecConverted.getTime() < new Date() && isTaf == true) {
        OwnMetarDoc.remove({
          _id: entry[0]._id
        }, function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log('old taf entry removed');
          };
        });
      }
      if (typeof callback === 'function') {
          callback()
      };
    };
  })
};
```

But this takes way too long when i have over 100'000 entries and multiple callbacks.

Does anybody knows if there is a way to achieve this quickly and automatically?

I know how to do it when I have to delete a document that is older than f.e eight hours within the Schema like this:

```
var ownMetarSchema = new Schema({
  STATION_ID: String,
  TIMERECASDATE: {
    type: Date,
    expires: 28800
  }
})
```

But I don't know how to do it with my previous example.

ps: I'm relatively new to Javascript and you may need some more information, just ask me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume that you would have used the `TTL` part, if you know how long your weather forecasts would be. Since you haven't used `TTL`, that means your forecast could be one day in the future or even one month (just for the discussion).

You are finding all the documents with `STATION_ID` and the parsing through it. Instead, you can do the following:

If you have a field `date` with the exact timestamp, then just run

`db.collection.remove({'date':{'$lt': new Date()} })`

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/

This will delete all the documents where the date is less than the current date. If you want, you can add the station_id field also. But for weather, I don’t think that is necessary.

I would recommend to do this delete in a separate thread/cron job, instead of doing it when you are pushing the data.

Comment: Haha thank you, i don't know why i dindnt seen this by myself before, that was the hint i needed :-). I import each 10 minutes a .xml file with all forecasts. This forecasts looks like weatherstation_id : from 2'00 AM - 10'AM: skyconditions : blabla, from 11'00AM - 8'00 PM: skyconditions: blabla . I then split the forecasts into one hour forecasts each, i check if the forecast already exists in the db and delete forecasts that aren't forecasts anymore and save it. Not sure if you will understand, english is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to update your document. You should read the mongo docs. Here : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/ You can just replace all value with your new value. Hope that helps.

Comment: No, i don't need to update it, these are weather forecasts that i save and when a  forecasts time is < new Date() i want to delete it.

Comment: Nevermind the last post, I understand what you want to do. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/ You will be able to set a TTL to your document. Once it expires it will be deleted.

Comment: Thank you, but i already looked at it and i can't figure out how to use it for my needs.